# filepicker.io Video lags when using the recorder

Tags: filepicker.io, filepicker

When using the record video feature in filepicker, does anyone else get a 3 or 4 second delay of the audio when playing the video back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. We are currently working on a fix.